# Add a javascript file in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, php, admin, javascript

I'm discovering magento since 1 week. But i have a problem now.
I need to include a javascript file in my admin panel to sort a list according to another.
I'm using magento 1.9 and i really don't find any tutorial to do this.

Please can someone explain me clearly how to do this because i'm really stuck at this point.

Comment: Do you want to add the js globally to your backend or just to a specifiv grid view? Are you using a module or just altering core files?

Comment: "(Ok, my message has been deleted, i don't know why...)" - because it is not an answer. Stack Exchange does not work like a forum. If you want to add details, **edit the question**. Only post an **answer** if you have a solution.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to choose a relevant layout(`.xml`) file based on the grid/page you want to include your javascript in.

Then in that layout you need to add the below code in the relevant section:

```
<layout>
  <adminhtml_{relevant_layout_handle}>
    <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>my_extension/adminhack.js</script></action>
            <action method="addJs"><script>prototype/prototype.js</script></action>         
        </reference>
  </adminhtml_{relevant_layout_handle}>
</layout>
```

Then you need to clear Magento caches and check if your file is loaded or not.

**Hope this works for you**

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create one module and with in module's layout file you can add a javascript and css using above answer syntax.